# Replacing pure virtual interfaces with lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I need to implement the following interface:

```
class xml_writer
{
public:
    virtual void write(const void* data, size_t size) = 0;
};
void xml_document::save(xml_writer& writer, const char_t* indent = "\t", unsigned int flags = format_default, xml_encoding encoding = encoding_auto) const;
```

I figured I could use a lambda like so:

```
// call save on XML passing lambda in place of xml_writer
std::array<char, 4096> request;
xml->save([&](const void* data, const std::size_t size) { std::memcpy(request.begin(), data, size); });
```

But alas it fails to compile in clang3.1!

Is it possible to use lambdas like this, i.e. in place of pure virtual inferfaces? My focus is reducing boilerplate code, not so much virtual function overhead.

Comment: Yes, with a wrapper class that inherits `xml_writer` and accepts a lambda during construction, stores it on a field, and executes it when `write()` is called.

Comment: And to store a lambda, you need a `std::function`, which uses virtual functions or something similar for the type erasure part, which saves you nothing in the end.

Comment: My goal is to reduce boilerplate, not so much performance.

Comment: Unfortunately C++ doesn't do duck typing. Just because the member functions are the same as `xml_writer` doesn't mean you can use it interchangeably, unless `xml_document::save` is a template function.

Comment: I kinda figured that, I guess it needs to bind to the name function name "write" whereas the lambda is annonymous

Comment: What happens when `size > 4096`? (If you omitted error checking for brevity, and you do check in your real code, then no problem, but that's not clear from your question.)

Comment: @Graeme: The lambda's not "anonymous", its code goes into an `operator()(const void*, std::size_t)` member.  Not sure what would happen if your `xml_writer` used `operator()()` instead of `write`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, so it's a functor, d'uh, I should have realised that. Unfortunately it's a 3rd party interface (pugixml) so I'm stuck with using the 'write' function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is no, you cannot use lambdas to implement interfaces. The only interface of a lambda is the required `operator()`, and that is non-virtual. Lambdas do not inherit from any type nor can they be inherited from.

What you can do is provide the definition of the extending type close to the use and implement the capture manually:

```
std::array<char,4096> request;
struct ToArrayWriter : xml_writer {
   ToArrayWriter(std::array<char,4096>& array) : array(array) {}
   void write( const void* data, size_t size ) {
      std::memcpy(&array[0],data,size);
   }
   std::array<char,4096>& array;
} writer(request);
xml->save( writer );
```

Comment: "Lambdas do not inherit from any type"?  They act as if they inherit an appropriate instantiation of `std::function`.

Comment: @Graeme: As of some rationales, consider that the pure virtual interface could have different names for the virtual function (what would be the name of the `operator()`?) and in most cases more than one pure virtual function (how would you implement all?). There would be very few cases where this could actually be used and the complexity of implementing (and using) the feature probably does not grant it.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's plainly not true, or else you'd be able to call e.g. `target` and `target_type` on the result of a lambda expression.

Comment: @BenVoigt: They implement `operator()`, but that is not acting as if they inherited from `std::function<>`. You could also say that `struct odd { bool operator()(int x) { return x&1;} };` acts as if it inherited from `std::function<bool(int)>` and yet I have implemented `odd` way before `std::function` was in the language...

Comment: @Luc: I've just been looking in 5.1.2 for any mention of a base type or lack thereof, and it seems to be unspecified.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It's also assignable to a `std::function<>` object.  Are instances of your `odd` object? (maybe they are)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Any callable is assignable to a `std::function`, that's the whole purpose of it (assuming matching signature). `std::function` is a polymorphic function wrapper.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Read the line *does not inherit from* as *the standard does not mandate that it inherits from* (i.e. you cannot depend on that). As if inheritance from `std::function` could be an option, I doubt it. `operator()` in `std::function` is not virtual, and you cannot bind a non-const reference `std::function<void()>& f = [](){};` (unless you are running VS, that is :))

Comment: @Xeo: Ok, I wonder what hoops the implementation jumps through to accomplish that.  Pointer to a holder object of polymorphic type, I suppose.

Comment: @David: It's not only not an option, *it wouldn't even make sense*. `std::function` *stores` a callable entity. If you inherit from it and expect things to work, you'd need to pass a copy of yourself to the parent `std::function`, which kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @BenVoigt: *Are instances of `odd` assignable to `std::function`?* Yes they are, as a matter of fact: `template< class F > function( F f );` is one of the constructors of `function` :) In the same way, a `weak_ptr` can be assigned from a `shared_ptr` and there is no inheritance relationship... Inheritance is the second most-coupling relationship in C++, assignable-from is a much less coupling relationship.

Comment: @BenVoigt: There are two implementations that I know of. One is, as you said, through virtual functions of an internal type and the other is basically an "emulation" of that with a `void*` pointer and a function pointer to function template instantiation that knows the correct types (see also [this ("Combating virtual function "bloat")](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/function/misc.html#id1565381)).

Comment: @David: Ok, you win.  (Still, your code snippet demonstrates absolutely nothing.  Either there's a converting constructor that creates a new `std::function` object, which is a temporary and can't bind to the reference, or else there's an upcast of a lambda object, which itself is a temporary and still can't bind to a reference.)

Comment: @BenVoigt: uhm... you are right, the proper code would be: `auto l = [](){}; std::function<void()> &r = l;`. Now in this case the upcast is of an lvalue and thus if `std::function<void()>` was a base of the lambda the reference would bind.

Comment: Lambdas can be, however, inherited from. It's tricky, but can be done: https://dev.to/tmr232/that-overloaded-trick-overloading-lambdas-in-c17